# How do you redefine a method like handle_asynchronously from delayed_jobs gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to call the handle_asynchronously method only in production mode (I don't want it to be used in development mode).

Here's what I want to do:

```
  def some_action_here
    puts "Some text here"
  end
  handle_production_asynchronously :some_action_here
```

I have something like this in an config/initializers file:

```
module Patch
  def handle_production_asynchronously(method, opts = {})
    Rails.env == "production" ? delay.method : method # Probably incorrect. What do I put here? 
  end
end

Module.send(:include,Patch)
```

What should I place in the initializers in the line above to execute the methods correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
module Patch
  def handle_production_asynchronously(method, opts = {})
    handle_asynchronously method if Rails.env == "production"
  end
end

Module.send(:include,Patch)
```